# Is it correct to use the conjunction “or” more than twice in one sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, punctuation, conjunctions, lists

For an example is it correct to say:

> You may use X or Y or Z or even something else.

And what is proper punctuation for such example in case it is valid.

Comment: The use of multiple conjunctions in quick succession could be a rhetorical device called [polysyndeton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polysyndeton), but you should probably only use it when trying to achieve a certain effect with your writing.

Comment: Crumbs, Cameron! Did you just happen to *know* that term? If not, how on earth did you find it? It's a shame OP didn't ask for the name.

Comment: @Cameron – you saved my day! This is exactly what I was lurking for but couldn’t find! I wanted to use “polysyndeton” because of a technical limitation that didn’t allow me to put a comma after a word (it was comma after the HTML link which is not part of the link but some software would interpret it as a part of the link). By the way I’m also asking you what FumbleFingers asked.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Sorry, didn't see your question earlier. Yes, I did happen to know that term (I learned it long ago in Latin class); I'm not sure why it stuck with me. Now if I could only remember where I left my keys…

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The statement as you gave it might occur in speech, but forms joined in this manner are not preferred in writing. Instead, separate the items with a comma, and put *or* only before the last item:

> You may use X, Y, Z, or even something else.

This is effectively the same as the rule for lists of items joined by *and*.

(Oxford comma forever!)

Comment: Did you mean Oxford, forever?

Comment: @Robusto No, he meant Oxford ",".

Comment: Thank you @JSBձոգչ for the answer. I was already knew that. I just wanted to know if such condition is considered as incorrect or not. Cameron made a valuable remark about “polysyndeton” as a comment to my question. I personally suggest to look at “Polysyndeton” article in Wikipedia.

Comment: @polysyndeton: Unquestionably most competent writers would agree your rendition without commas is "incorrect". The fact that there's a technical term for what's primarily a literary style device, rather than an acceptable way of solving an HTML formatting issue, has no real bearing on the acceptability or otherwise of your example.