# Does "or", "and" at the end of a list determines meaning of the list?

Tags: grammar, conjunctions, lists, coordinating-conjunctions

I am confused with usage of "or" in a list. I found a similar question, [Is it correct to use the conjunction “or” more than twice in one sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/84456/is-it-correct-to-use-the-conjunction-or-more-than-twice-in-one-sentence) but this is not what I am looking for. Here is an example:

I want to say Ms. A wants to marry Mr. B or Mr. C or Mr. D.

In this case, is the following sentence correct? Ms. A wants to marry Mr. B, Mr. C,  ***or*** Mr. D.

Does the "or" at the end says that the list is connected by or?

I know that if were "and" in place of or (Ms. A wants to marry Mr. B, Mr. C,  ***and*** Mr. D), the sentence completely changes in meaning and means Ms. A wants to marry Mr. B and Mr. C, and Mr. D.

Thus, the coordinating conjunction "and", "or" at the end of the list determines whether list elements are connected by "and" or "or"?

Comment: I'm confused... There's no difference between "Mr. B, Mr. C, and Mr.D" and "Mr. B and Mr. C and Mr. D"...

Comment: Your assumptions are correct for simple lists.

Comment: @Catija OP is not suggesting there is a difference between the 2 versions you list.  As I understand it, OP is asking whether "A, B & C" *always* means "A & B & C" (*i.e.* always requiring all 3 options, & never less); and likewise whether "A, B or C" *always* means "A or B or C" (*i.e.* always only 1 choice, never any combination).

Comment: @Catija what? If I ask you "Would you prefer steak, chicken, ***or*** tofu for dinner?" versus "Would you prefer steak, chicken, ***and*** dinner for dinner?", there's a vast difference between them. The first is asking for your choice of the three, and the second is asking if you'd like all three together.

Comment: @PierceDarragh I never use "or" in either of my versions.

Comment: @Catija I know of no way to give both possible interpretations without further rewording beyond the "and/or" distinction. The second sentence I gave cannot mean both things.

Comment: @PierceDarragh And I don't understand why the OP thinks that using "or" in place of "and" wouldn't turn it into an exclusive list. If the OP knows that one "and" in a list is sufficient, then it follows that one "or" in a list is sufficient. The only way this would be confusing is if, for some reason, the OP thinks that commas in lists **mean** "and"... which they do not.

Comment: @Catija sorry, I guess I read your first comment as a blanket statement, which could mislead OP. I see now that you probably meant *in this case*, but the lack of specificity confused me. My mistake.

Comment: As @TrevorD pointed out, I want to ask whether A, B, or C means "A or B or C".

Answer (score 1):

Normally, when you use a single conjunction in at the end of the list, it's assumed to apply to the entire list. So *A, B, or C* typically means a choice between the 3 items, while *A, B, and C* means all the items are collected together. The comma by itself doesn't imply any specific way of joining the items around it, so the conjunction at the end supplies that meaning.

However, there may be some specific contexts where the logic makes this meaning unlikely, and common sense clears it up. For instance

> She wants to marry Mr. A, Mr. B, and Mr. C.

doesn't make sense if you interpret it that she wants to marry them all at the same time, because that's not permissible in most societies. So it would be interpreted that she's interested in each of them, not them all as a group.

Comment: While I do agree with the common sense part, I believe it is not good to leave it open to reader's interpretation. And then, what if she actually meant to marry all three at the same (irrespective of or ignorant of permissibility)?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't design human beings, we don't operate by strict rules, and many things in language are up to interpretation. If she really does intend to marry all three, she had better say so explicitly, or most people will not understand.

Comment: I see what you mean; point taken!